# How to bring back selected rows from datagridview to TextBox

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm having a problem understanding what code I can use bring back selected rows from data grid view to the text boxes to edit. I think we will use something like `dataScreen.SelectedRows` something maybe

What code can I use?

DataSource = datagridview (to make it easier to understand)

```
namespace HospitalManagementSystem
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {         
         DataTable table = new DataTable();

         public string name { get; set; }
         public string Gender { get; set; }
         public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
         public string Address { get; set; }
         public string MedicalHistory { get; set; }
         public string BloodType { get; set; }

         public Form1()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }

         private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             this.Close();
         }

         private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
              dataScreen.Rows.Add("Iqra", "Female", 20, 721797684, "praha 6", "Migraine", "Blood Type O+");
         }

         private void radioButton_Male_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
              Gender = "Male";
         }

         private void radioButton_Female_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
              Gender = "Female";
         }

         private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
              name = txtName.Text;
              DateOfBirth = Date_dob.Value.ToString();
              Address = txtAddress.Text;
              MedicalHistory = txtMedicalHistory.Text;
              BloodType = txtBloodType.Text;

              if (radioButton_Female.Checked)
                  Gender = "Female";
              else if (radioButton_Male.Checked)
                  Gender = "Male";

              dataScreen.Rows.Add(name, Gender, DateOfBirth, Address, MedicalHistory);
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you replace the DataSource of your dataScreen with the value of your table when you click on save.

```
 dataScreen.DataSource = table;
```

That is what's replacing the value of dataScreen.DataSource.

Depending on what you are trying to do you might want to add that row to the table before you update your dataScreen.DataSource.

Comment: oh! i get it i deleted "dataScreen.DataSource = table;" and added "dataScreen.Rows.Add(name, Gender, DateOfBirth, Address, MedicalHistory);"  and it works  thanks